# Ubuntu 20.04 take too long time to open some apps after install an Input method

Tags: apt, uefi, vlc, ibus

I still enjoy to use Ubuntu version 20.04 But recently I had a bit of a problem when I reinstalled the system in UEFI mode instead of Legacy. Exactly when I installed ibus-unikey as the new input method, VLC, KDE and some other applications take too long to start (20s or more). And when I run `sudo apt autoremove ibus-unikey` and remove its repository, VLC start immediately.
So what exactly is the problem? How do I solve it?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information about my system.

Comment: Ahhh. I understand what you mean. thank you!! But do we have any solution here so I can still use input method app without affecting system apps? When I uninstalled ```ibus``` VLC and other applications open immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found it, it's a conflict between gtk versions. When installing I noticed it installs both
`ibus-gtk` and `ibus-gtk3` packages. So just remove it
`sudo apt remove ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3`. Problem solved.
Vote 1 up for me if this helps you.

Comment: Sorry,,, Just ```remove ibus-gtk```. because remove ibus-gtk3 it leads to some error.